# Why can't I use python and selenium to click this particular button by id, xpath or coordinates?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver

So I was trying to automate some reports at my job and found it impossible to progress beyond a certain point where a new tab is opened and I am trying to make it click on the custom reports button.  Website, pw and username are all fake in this example.  My current code is below and everything works up until the custom reports buttons.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

usernameStr = 'randomemail@whocares.com'
passwordStr = 'hunter2(jokepassword)'
report = 'Experiment'

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get(('www.fakeurlIjustmadeup.com'))

username = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gb-login-form .gb-user-input input')
username.send_keys(usernameStr)

password = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gb-login-form .gb-user-pwd input')))
password.send_keys(passwordStr)

loginButton = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.gb-login-form .gb-login-button button')
loginButton.click()

reportsTab = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#reports')
reportsTab.click()

reportsButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'SearchReports')))
reportsButton.click()


browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])


#Custom Report Not Working with ID
#customButton = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "AddCustomReport")))
#customButton.click()

#Custom Report Not Working with xpath
#customButton = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="AddCustomReport"]')
#customButton.click()

time.sleep(10)
```

The way I was identifying the path is by right clicking the button and asking for the path.  The html looks something like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<input id="CustomReportsViewModel" name="CustomReportsViewModel" type="hidden" value="{&quot;IsCustomReportLibrary&quot;:true,&quot;SchoolId&quot;:1,&quot;YearId&quot;:11,&quot;IsTeacher&quot;:false,&quot;MqAddEditVM&quot;:null,&quot;ModuleQueryInfoList&quot;:[{&quot;QueryID&quot;:1083,&quot;QueryNumber&quot;:0,&quot;QueryName&quot;:&quot;Experiment&quot;,&quot;SchoolId&quot;:0,&quot;YearID&quot;:0,&quot;CreatdDate&quot;:&quot;\/Date(-62135596800000)\/&quot;,&quot;QueryOnType&quot;:&quot;Scores&quot;,&quot;CreatorType&quot;:null,&quot;CreatorId&quot;:null,&quot;IsExtraQueryType&quot;:false,&quot;IsIncludeWithDrawn&quot;:false,&quot;IsQueryEnabled&quot;:false,&quot;IsDefaultQuery&quot;:false,&quot;IsAbsScoreType&quot;:false}],&quot;CourseFields&quot;:null,&quot;SectionFields&quot;:null,&quot;MQAvilableFieldsCol&quot;:null}">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="305gVOidQElbfPBJ0-6t5tg3XYbLZwDnZciZYpr0PaXwroXTFjRqLUXHr1XC8W9eSO8ISMYqGFycTseQILfNPTQ7IMFETzXY-pf4CXj_n1A1">
<div class="border-bottom wrapper white-bg page-heading m-b">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <h2>Reports Library</h2>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="MainGridReports">

    <div class="page-wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-12 bottom-space-fix">
            <div class="ibox float-e-margins ibox-title no-padding">
                <div class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="btn-row">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="AddCustomReport">Add Custom Report</button>
                            
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        <h3>Default Reports</h3>
                        <div id="gridDefaultReport" data-role="tooltip" class="k-grid k-widget k-display-block" style=""><div>
<style>
    *[role="row"] {
      height: 34px !important;
    }
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried using ID and xpath with python and selenium but neither id would click on the custom reports button.

Comment: probably because they have taken specific steps to protect against this ... why not try printing the document you are getting back and seeing what you are getting instead of what you think you are getting ...

Comment: I think that upon creating the new tab, selenium probably lost control. first, you switch the control to a new tab and process your other activity.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Joran.  After adding print statements I can confirm that nothing happens after the browser switches to a new window but am still unsure why it finds it impossible to click the button given the proper ID, xpath or coordinates.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion Bhairu.  Does the code browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1]) not do that?  I am rather new at using selenium and am just learning some of the basics.  I got this to work when I was logging into google accounts and accessing sheets that open in a new tab this way  with another program.

Comment: The index of the window handle is not guaranteed to be in order.  You should get the current window handle before doing the action that opens the new window.  Then get all windows handles after.  Iterate over the array and find the one that is not the current handle.  See here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/

Comment: pcalkins you were right.  I edited my code as follows to confirm window selection

current_window = browser.current_window_handle
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
new_window = [window for window in browser.window_handles if window != current_window][0]
browser.switch_to.window(new_window)

This fixed the issue.